# Global Variable is not Updating

Tags: python, global-variables, counter

My global variable is not updating, all it prints out is 0. Why is this happening? Are global variables bad practice?

```
counter = 0
def count():
    global counter
    print(counter)
    counter += 1
    return counter

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count()
```

Comment: Well you are only calling it once. Call it twice and it will print out `1` the second time

Comment: you are printing it out before 1 is added to it and only doing this once

Comment: I understand my issue now. Would it be possible to retain how many times the main is run. For example I run the main once and the number becomes 1, would it be possible to reassign the value of counter to be 1 so the next time main is run the counter becomes 2? That was what I was attempting to do.

Comment: `counter` is reset to 0 every time you run the program. If you want to save the value *between* runs, you need to store the current value in, say, a file before the program exists, and read it back from the file when the program starts.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I will attempt to do so. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @AlyssaHuque if you need to retain the value between calls you need to store the value outside of the main program. Just like other languages, that data is not persistent across multiple program calls. You could store the value in a text file or make it more complicated and use a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You print it first, and only afterwards change its value. If you move

```
counter += 1
```

*above* the `print` line, you will see it prints `1`.

It will only print this once, not continuously. Since you are not calling `count` inside a loop of some kind, it will only update and print the result once.

Comment: oh I see, thank you for explaining. Would it be possible to retain how many times the main is run. For example I run the main once and the number becomes 1, would it be possible to reassign the value of counter to be 1 so the next time main is run the counter becomes 2? That was what I was attempting to do.

Comment: No; you need to use the file system or something similar if you want changes to `counter` to persist between runs of the program.

Answer (score 0):

- you are returning updated counter value so just print that.

```
counter = 0
def count():
    global counter
    print(counter)
    counter += 1
    return counter

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(count())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to print after you add one to see the addition

```
counter = 0
def count():
    global counter 
    counter += 1
    print(counter)
    return counter

if __name__ == "__main__":
    count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of permanent storage to remember the value of `counter` between runs. For example,

```
import os

counter_file = "..."   # some file name

def count():
    global counter
    print(counter)
    counter += 1
    return counter

if __name__ == "__main__":

    if not os.path.exists(counter_file):
        counter = 0
    else:
        with open(counter_file) as f:
            counter = int(f.read())

    count()

    with open(counter_file) as f:
        print(counter, file=f)
```